# What will this xpath query select?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xpath query which seems to be working but I just want to be sure its not incorrect:

```
//link[@type='application/rss+xml' or @type='application/atom+xml' and @rel='alternate']
```

The purpose is to do feed autodiscovery from a web page.

What I want it to do is:

```
all link tags with either (rss or atom) and rel alternate
```

but what I suspect it is doing is

```
all link tags with either (rss) or (atom and rel alternate)
```

Can anyone clarify if this is the case and also provide the correct query if I have made a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply avoid that ambiguity and put two of those three conditions in parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr), `and` has higher precedence than `or`. So, the latter would be the correct interpretation. You'll need to add parenthesis to group the `@type` expressions together.

Comment: Thank you. I know it was terribly lazy of me to lean on the community and I am not normally like this but I haven't got on well with the xpath in the past and I really needed to be sure. Thanks again!